# BASH SCRIPT - save in memory then read

Tags: sql, bash, nagios

Someone can tell if it is possible, save a variable(a number (this number is a total of rows in a SQL tabel)) in like a memory or a file? and then, like 5 min later, check if the number is the same? and send me like a warning or alert for nagios?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

OLD_NUM=`command_to_get_number`
while true
do
  sleep 5m
  NEW_NUM=`command_to_get_number`

  [ "$OLD_NUM" != "$NEW_NUM" ] && notify-send "Number changed"

  OLD_NUM="$NEW_NUM"
done
```

`notify-send` will give you a desktop notification, not sure if there is a similar command to work with nagios.

Comment: nagios captures stdout, so he would want `echo` instead of `notify-send`. Also a relevant exit code for warning or critical alert.